# Данные из объекта в массив (JS)

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты, преобразование

Балуюсь с созданием калькулятора для матриц. Вижу, что было бы удобно пользоваться объектами, поскольку каждому элементу матрицы можно будет присвоить своё некоторое имя (в нашем случае это свойство объекта), а потом этими именами оперировать для совершения множества весьма объёмных арифметических операций.

Однако у меня никак не получается значения свойств объекта:

```
var m1 = {
    x11: 1,
    x12: 2,
    x13: 3,
    x21: 4,
    x22: 5,
    x23: 6,
    x31: 7,
    x32: 8,
    x33: 9
}
```

перенести в таблицу:

```
    <table id="matrix1">
        <tr id="matrix1_tr1">
            <td id="matrix1_td1"></td>
            <td id="matrix1_td2"></td>
            <td id="matrix1_td3"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="tr2">
            <td id="matrix1_td4"></td>
            <td id="matrix1_td5"></td>
            <td id="matrix1_td6"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="tr2">
            <td id="matrix1_td7"></td>
            <td id="matrix1_td8"></td>
            <td id="matrix1_td9"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Проблем с наполнением таблицы через массив у меня не возникает. Не возникает также проблем с наполнением и массивов, и объектов случайными числами.

Также пробовал наполнить массив (пока не таблицу, разметка которой выше, а массив для тренировки):

1. с помощью перебора свойств for..in. Но на выходе массив выходит пустым.
2. с помощью цикла for. А в этом случае, массив наполнен, но значениями undefined.

Вопрос могу сформулировать следующим образом: **как мне перенести значения из объекта m1  в таблицу #matrix1**? К примеру, в нашем случае в ячейке с идентификатором #matrix1_td4 будет значение 4, а в ячейке с идентификатором #matrix1_td9 будет значение 9.

Comment: А никак. Только вручную. Ну или парсингом имени поля (кстати, когда строк или колонок будет больше 9, что будете делать?) А был бы у Вас обычный двумерный массив - никаких проблем бы не было

Comment: Попробуйте динамически строить таблицу по тем данным, что у вас есть. Пробовали так?

Answer (score 0):

Если допустимо вносить изменения в html

```js
var m1 = {
x11: 1,
x12: 2,
x13: 3,
x21: 4,
x22: 5,
x23: 6,
x31: 7,
x32: 8,
x33: 9
} 
for(var key in m1)
document.getElementById(key).innerHTML= m1[key]
```

```html
<table id="matrix1">
    <tr id="matrix1_tr1">
        <td id="x11"></td>
        <td id="x12"></td>
        <td id="x13"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr2">
        <td id="x21"></td>
        <td id="x22"></td>
        <td id="x23"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr2">
        <td id="x31">3</td>
        <td id="x32"></td>
        <td id="x33"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
window.onload = function(){
  var m1 = {
    x11: 1,
    x12: 2,
    x13: 3,
    x21: 4,
    x22: 5,
    x23: 6,
    x31: 7,
    x32: 8,
    x33: 9,
    x41:10,
    x42:11,
    x43:12,
} 

var table = document.createElement("table");
table.id = "matrix1_tr1";
table.border = "1px"
var oneKeys = [];

for(var key in m1){
  var OK = key.match(/\w(\d)\d/)[1];
  if(oneKeys.indexOf(OK)<0)oneKeys.push(OK);
}

for(var i = 0;i<oneKeys.length;i++){
  var tr = document.createElement("tr");
  tr.id = "matrix1_tr"+oneKeys[i];
    for(var key in m1){
    var OK = key.match(/\w(\d)\d/)[1];
    if(OK == oneKeys[i]){
      var td = document.createElement("td");
      td.id = "matrix1_td"+m1[key];
      td.innerHTML = m1[key];
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
   
  }
  table.appendChild(tr);
}
document.body.appendChild(table);}
```

```html
<html><head></head><title></title><body></body></html>
```